# Extending of a set function to a linear transformation

Tags: vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $V$ and $W$ are vector spaces over a field $F$. Let $B$ be a basis of $V$, then prove that  every set function $f:B→W$ extends uniquely to a linear transformation  $T:V→W$.
I can't conclude how to show this. please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $B$ is a basis, any element of $V$ can be written as a linear combination of elements of $B$, i.e. if $v \in V$ and $B=\{x_1,\ldots , x_n\}$, then there exist scalars $c_i$ such that
$$v = c_1 x_1 + \cdots + c_n x_n.$$

You have a function $f$ that sends each $x_i$ to some element of $W$.
Since we want $T$ to extend $f$, it must be that $T(x_i)=f(x_i)$ for each $x_i \in B$. Then, what does linearity of $T$ tell you about $T(v)$?